# Boto to Boto3 function implementation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, boto3, aws-cli

1) How can i implement this from boto into boto3 code:

```
conn = boto.connect_ec2()  # boto way
sgs = conn.get_all_security_groups()  # boto way
for sg in sgs:
    if len(sg.instances()) == 0:
        print(sg.name, sg.id, len(sg.instances()))
```

The above code basically prints all Security Groups with no instances attached.

---

2) And this individual command which uses `duct.sh()` module :

```
command = 'aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=instance.group-id,Values=' + sg.id + '\" --query \'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,Tags[?Key==`Name`]  | [0].Value]\' --output json'
```

Comment: sounds a lot like 'write the code for me' so suggest you read boto 3 doc (http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_security_groups) and for 2 check http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances

Comment: What are you actually asking in the second part of your question? Feel free to create a separate Question if it is unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

boto: `get_all_security_groups()`

boto3: `security_group_iterator = ec2.security_groups.all()`

However, boto has the `.instances()` method on `boto.ec2.securitygroup.SecurityGroup`, whereas boto3 does not have an equivalent method on `ec2.SecurityGroup`.

Therefore, it looks like you would have to call `describe_instances()`, passing the security group as a `Filter`:

```
response = client.describe_instances(
  Filters=[{'Name':'instance.group-id','Values':['sg-abcd1234']}])
```

This will return a list of instances that use the given security group.

You could then count `len(response['Reservations'])` to find unused security groups. (Note: This is an easy way to find zero-length responses, but to count the actual instances would require adding up all `Reservations.Instances`.)

Comment: awesome going to try this out. I couldnt find the method in boto3.